# facing difficulties in Json parsing in groovy

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jsonparser

I have a json and its response is `{"canMerge":false,"conflicted":true,"outcome":"CONFLICTED","vetoes":[{"summaryMessage":"Requires approvals","detailedMessage":"You need 2 more approvals before this pull request can be merged."}]}`

and I want to filter out data on the basis of `"outcome":"CONFLICTED"` for this I have tried following ways-

```
def mergeResponse = readJSON file:mergeFileName
for(mergenew in mergeResponse.values)
{
    if(mergenew.outcome == "CONFLICTED") {
          echo "pull request can not merged"
}
```

when I am trying above it is skipping if loop directly eventhough condition match properly I am not getting why?
**ALSO TRIED BELOW**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(mergenew)
assert slurper.outcome == "CONFLICTED"
     String id = mergenew.getString("id");
     echo "pull request can not merged"
```

*getting error for above is*

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseFile() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap$ListOrderedMapEntry) values: [canMerge=false]
Possible solutions: parse([B), parse([C), parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.net.URL)
```

I also approved script in jenkins script approval for *JsonSlurper.parseText*

Please help me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

try this : (set the file name var to whatever the file is)

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
data = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(mergeFileName))
assert data.outcome == "CONFLICTED"
       println("pull request can not merged")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) to read a json file. This works for me:

```
def data = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/data.json" // here just read the json file
def outcome = "${data.outcome}"
if(outcome == "CONFLICTED") {
    echo "pull request can not merged"
}
```

Comment: I tried this but getting error-
`an exception which occurred:
 in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
 in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LoopBlockScopeEnv@2c73fea7
 in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
 in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@6e7ce95d
 in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent`